# Why is my function terminating by itself when it should be calling another function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, linked-list

I'm making a library program where people can browse and donate books. It has 3 books stored in linked list initially. When they donate, their donation is added to the linked list so when they browse again, the books will have increased.

(I have declared `void menu()` up at the very top)

(The arrangement is `menu(), donate(), browse(), initialize()` from bottom to top respectively)

Here's the menu:

```
void menu()
{
    int choice;
    char repeat;

    do{
        system("cls");
        cout<<"1. Browse books"<<endl;
        cout<<"2. Donate books"<<endl;
        cin>>choice;

        if (choice==1)
        {
            browse();
        } else if (choice==2)
        {
            donate();
        } else
        {
            cout<<"Input not valid. Try again."<<endl;
            menu();
        }
        cout<<"Do you want to go back to menu?(Y/N)"<<endl;
        cin>>repeat;
    } while (repeat=='y'||repeat=='Y');
}
```

Here's the donate:

```
void donate()
{
    int amount;
    cout<<"How many books are you donating? ";
    cin>>amount;
    string donation[amount];
    cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 

    cout<<"Enter the titles:"<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<amount; i+=1)
    {
        getline(cin, donation[i]);
    }

    for(int k=0; k<amount; k+=1)
    {
        newbook = new node;
        newbook->bookname = donation[k];
        newbook->next = NULL;
        tail->next = newbook;
        tail = newbook;
    }
}
```

Here's the browse: (I made it loop 10 times coz idk how many books they're gonna donate and I can't pass the `amount` from `donate()` to here bcs it mean that the function will have to accept a parameter and when called from the menu, it has no `amount` yet.) (I know this slows the program but idk how else to do this. If anyone has any idea please tell me.)

```
void browse()
{   
    display = head;
    cout<<"We have these books in our collection:"<<endl;
    for (int i=1; i<=10; i+=1)
    {
        cout<<display->bookname<<endl;
        display = display->next;
    }
}
```

Here's the initialization: (these are the 3 books initially present in the library)

```
void initialize()
{
    head= new node;
    second= new node;
    tail= new node;

    head->bookname = "Book1";
    head->next = second;

    second->bookname = "Book2";
    second->next = tail;

    tail->bookname = "Book3";
    tail->next = NULL;
}
```

If they browse after donating, it works fine. But if they browse without donating, it shows the initial 3 books then terminates itself, not looping back to the menu. Why does it do this? Shouldn't it just loop 10 times (slow, I know) then loop back to the menu?

Comment: You mean the program crashes ? have you initialized display structures correctly ?

Comment: Repeatedly calling `menu()` will exhaust your stack space eventually. Instead use a loop within your `menu` function.

Comment: You need to change the logic flow of the program. These functions call eachother indefinitely but they should actually return at some point. You are not "going back to menu", you are calling it again.

Comment: A true [mre] should have no need to go into the background of why you are writing this code. Focus on just the abstract: menu and options. Get rid of as much I/O as reasonable, using comments to clue us into what you've taken out. *(Displaying the books would be kept, as that seems to be where the problem lies.)* Remember: we are looking to reproduce your bug, not admire your user interface.

Comment: By "terminates itself" you mean the *program* stops running? (Grammatically, I would have tied "it" to "function", but "program" seems a better fit semantically.) A more common term for that is "crash".

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get used to using 0-based iteration. It matches better with arrays and pretty much everything else in the language. That is, instead of `for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1)` use `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you browse when there are not 10 books in the collection, then you'll presumably fall off the end of the linked list.  `display->next` will be null, so null will be assigned to `display`, and then `display->bookname` will fail with a null dereference.

Or so I assume, not seeing your linked-list implementation.

You need to terminate the browse loop not after an arbitrary 10 books but when you reach the end of the linked list.  Presumably this is when display is null.

```
   while (display != null) {
       ...output...
       display = display->next;  
   }
```

---

Additionally, you're doomed to stack overflow.  Consider a user that donates a book, browses, donates a book, browses...

You call chain is then menu => donate => menu => browse => menu => donate => menu => browse ….  and sooner or later you'll run out of stack.

The same is true elsewhere. For example, suppose the user is in menu() and just keeps typing '3' time and time again.

You don't need the recursive structure. menu should probably just have a big loop around most of its code.